# Pytorch, what are the gradient arguments

Tags: neural-network, gradient, pytorch, torch, gradient-descent

I am reading through the documentation of PyTorch and found an example where they write

```
gradients = torch.FloatTensor([0.1, 1.0, 0.0001])
y.backward(gradients)
print(x.grad)
```

where x was an initial variable, from which y was constructed (a 3-vector). The question is, what are the 0.1, 1.0 and 0.0001 arguments of the gradients tensor ? The documentation is not very clear on that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> The original code I haven't found on PyTorch website anymore.

```
gradients = torch.FloatTensor([0.1, 1.0, 0.0001])
y.backward(gradients)
print(x.grad)
```

The problem with the code above is there is no function based on how to calculate the gradients. This means we don't know how many parameters (arguments the function takes) and the dimension of parameters.

To fully understand this I created an example close to the original:

> Example 1:

```
a = torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], requires_grad = True)
b = torch.tensor([3.0, 4.0, 5.0], requires_grad = True)
c = torch.tensor([6.0, 7.0, 8.0], requires_grad = True)

y=3*a + 2*b*b + torch.log(c)    
gradients = torch.FloatTensor([0.1, 1.0, 0.0001])
y.backward(gradients,retain_graph=True)    

print(a.grad) # tensor([3.0000e-01, 3.0000e+00, 3.0000e-04])
print(b.grad) # tensor([1.2000e+00, 1.6000e+01, 2.0000e-03])
print(c.grad) # tensor([1.6667e-02, 1.4286e-01, 1.2500e-05])
```

I assumed our function is `y=3*a + 2*b*b + torch.log(c)` and the parameters are tensors with three elements inside.

You can think of the `gradients = torch.FloatTensor([0.1, 1.0, 0.0001])` like this is the accumulator.

As you may hear, PyTorch autograd system calculation is equivalent to Jacobian product.

[image: Jacobian]

In case you have a function, like we did:

```
y=3*a + 2*b*b + torch.log(c)
```

Jacobian would be `[3, 4*b, 1/c]`. However, this [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) is not how PyTorch is doing things to calculate the gradients at a certain point.

PyTorch uses forward pass and [backward mode automatic differentiation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.05767.pdf) (AD) in tandem.

There is no symbolic math involved and no numerical differentiation.

> Numerical differentiation would be to calculate `δy/δb`, for `b=1` and `b=1+ε` where ε is small.

If you don't use gradients in `y.backward()`:

> Example 2

```
a = torch.tensor(0.1, requires_grad = True)
b = torch.tensor(1.0, requires_grad = True)
c = torch.tensor(0.1, requires_grad = True)
y=3*a + 2*b*b + torch.log(c)

y.backward()

print(a.grad) # tensor(3.)
print(b.grad) # tensor(4.)
print(c.grad) # tensor(10.)
```

You will simply get the result at a point, based on how you set your `a`, `b`, `c` tensors initially.

Be careful how you initialize your `a`, `b`, `c`:

> Example 3:

```
a = torch.empty(1, requires_grad = True, pin_memory=True)
b = torch.empty(1, requires_grad = True, pin_memory=True)
c = torch.empty(1, requires_grad = True, pin_memory=True)

y=3*a + 2*b*b + torch.log(c)

gradients = torch.FloatTensor([0.1, 1.0, 0.0001])
y.backward(gradients)

print(a.grad) # tensor([3.3003])
print(b.grad) # tensor([0.])
print(c.grad) # tensor([inf])
```

If you use `torch.empty()` and don't use `pin_memory=True` you may have different results each time.

Also, note gradients are like accumulators so zero them when needed.

> Example 4:

```
a = torch.tensor(1.0, requires_grad = True)
b = torch.tensor(1.0, requires_grad = True)
c = torch.tensor(1.0, requires_grad = True)
y=3*a + 2*b*b + torch.log(c)

y.backward(retain_graph=True)
y.backward()

print(a.grad) # tensor(6.)
print(b.grad) # tensor(8.)
print(c.grad) # tensor(2.)
```

Lastly few tips on terms PyTorch uses:

PyTorch creates a **dynamic computational graph** when calculating the gradients in forward pass. This looks much like a tree.

So you will often hear the *leaves* of this tree are **input tensors** and the *root* is **output tensor**.

Gradients are calculated by tracing the graph from the root to the leaf and multiplying every gradient in the way using the **chain rule**. This multiplying occurs in the backward pass.

Back some time I created [PyTorch Automatic Differentiation tutorial](https://programming-review.com/pytorch/ad) that you may check interesting explaining all the tiny details about AD.

Comment: Great answer! However, I don't think Pytorch does numerical differentiation ("For the previous function PyTorch would do for instance δy/δb, for b=1 and b=1+ε where ε is small. So there is nothing like symbolic math involved.") - I believe it does automatic differentiation.

Comment: Yes, it uses AD, or automatic differentiation, later I investigated AD further like in this [PDF](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.05767.pdf), however, when I set this answer I was not quite informed.

Comment: E.g. example 2 gives RuntimeError: Mismatch in shape: grad_output[0] has a shape of torch.Size([3]) and output[0] has a shape of torch.Size([]).

Comment: @AndreasK., you were right, PyTorch introduced recently [zero sized tensors](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-fix-mismatch-in-shape-when-using-backward-function/58865) and this had the impact on my previous examples. Removed since these examples were not crucial.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, but for anyone interested, the Jacobian image is taken from [this Coursera lecture](https://www.coursera.org/learn/multivariate-calculus-machine-learning/lecture/BfvWV/the-jacobian) (minute 0:45; requires login).

Answer (score 121):

## Explanation

For neural networks, we usually use `loss` to assess how well the network has learned to classify the input image (or other tasks). The `loss` term is usually a scalar value. In order to update the parameters of the network, we need to calculate the gradient of `loss` w.r.t to the parameters, which is actually `leaf node` in the computation graph (by the way, these parameters are mostly the weight and bias of various layers such Convolution, Linear and so on).

According to chain rule, in order to calculate gradient of `loss` w.r.t to a leaf node, we can compute derivative of `loss` w.r.t some intermediate variable, and gradient of intermediate variable w.r.t to the leaf variable, do a dot product and sum all these up.

The `gradient` arguments of a `Variable`'s [`backward()`](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/autograd.html#torch.autograd.Variable.backward) method is used to **calculate a weighted sum of each element of a Variable w.r.t the [leaf Variable](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/leaf-variable-was-used-in-an-inplace-operation/308/2?u=jdhao).** These weight is just the derivate of final `loss` w.r.t each element of the intermediate variable.

## A concrete example

Let's take a concrete and simple example to understand this.

```py
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch
x = Variable(torch.FloatTensor([[1, 2, 3, 4]]), requires_grad=True)
z = 2*x
loss = z.sum(dim=1)

# do backward for first element of z
z.backward(torch.FloatTensor([[1, 0, 0, 0]]), retain_graph=True)
print(x.grad.data)
x.grad.data.zero_() #remove gradient in x.grad, or it will be accumulated

# do backward for second element of z
z.backward(torch.FloatTensor([[0, 1, 0, 0]]), retain_graph=True)
print(x.grad.data)
x.grad.data.zero_()

# do backward for all elements of z, with weight equal to the derivative of
# loss w.r.t z_1, z_2, z_3 and z_4
z.backward(torch.FloatTensor([[1, 1, 1, 1]]), retain_graph=True)
print(x.grad.data)
x.grad.data.zero_()

# or we can directly backprop using loss
loss.backward() # equivalent to loss.backward(torch.FloatTensor([1.0]))
print(x.grad.data)
```

In the above example, the outcome of first `print` is

> 2  0  0  0
>   [torch.FloatTensor of size 1x4]

which is exactly the derivative of z_1 w.r.t to x.

The outcome of second `print` is :

> 0  2  0  0
>   [torch.FloatTensor of size 1x4]

which is the derivative of z_2 w.r.t to x.

Now if use a weight of [1, 1, 1, 1] to calculate the derivative of z w.r.t to x, the outcome is `1*dz_1/dx + 1*dz_2/dx + 1*dz_3/dx + 1*dz_4/dx`. So no surprisingly, the output of 3rd `print` is:

> 2  2  2  2
>   [torch.FloatTensor of size 1x4]

It should be noted that weight vector [1, 1, 1, 1] is exactly derivative of `loss` w.r.t to z_1, z_2, z_3 and z_4. The derivative of `loss` w.r.t to `x` is calculated as:

```
d(loss)/dx = d(loss)/dz_1 * dz_1/dx + d(loss)/dz_2 * dz_2/dx + d(loss)/dz_3 * dz_3/dx + d(loss)/dz_4 * dz_4/dx
```

So the output of 4th `print` is the same as the 3rd `print`:

> 2  2  2  2
>   [torch.FloatTensor of size 1x4]

Comment: just a doubt, why are we calculating *x.grad.data* for gradients for loss or z.

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but I feel like the official documentation really could have explained the `gradient` argument better. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The official docs assume that you have a good understanding of the underlying theory, which is not always the case -_-#

Comment: @jdhao *"It should be noted that weight vector `[1, 1, 1, 1]` is exactly derivative of `loss` w.r.t to `z_1`, `z_2`, `z_3` and `z_4`."* I think this statement is really key to the answer. When looking at the OP's code a big question mark is where do these [arbitrary (magic) numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) for the gradient come from. In your concrete example I think it would be very helpful to point out the relation between the e.g. `[1, 0, 0 0]` tensor and the `loss` function right away so one can see that the values aren't arbitrary in this example.

Comment: @jdhao I think the exact derivative of the `loss` w.r.t `z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4` is `[2,2,2,2]`. And the gradient argument of the `backward()` is the weight that will multiply to the derivative. That's why `[2,2,2,2] * [1,1,1,1] = [2,2,2,2]` (the tensor element-wise multiplication).

Comment: @a_guest And though I haven't fully appreciated why we need a weighted derivative, I think the weight gradient argument is just an element-wise weight for the partial derivative *at the input tensor value point*.

Comment: @smwikipedia, that is not true. If we expand `loss = z.sum(dim=1)`, it will become `loss = z_1 + z_2 + z_3 + z_4`. If you know simple calculus, you will know that the derivative of `loss` w.r.t to `z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4` is `[1, 1, 1, 1]`.

Answer (score 56):

Typically, your computational graph has one scalar output says `loss`. Then you can compute the gradient of `loss` w.r.t. the weights (`w`) by `loss.backward()`. Where the default argument of `backward()` is `1.0`.

If your output has multiple values (e.g. `loss=[loss1, loss2, loss3]`), you can compute the gradients of loss w.r.t. the weights by `loss.backward(torch.FloatTensor([1.0, 1.0, 1.0]))`.

Furthermore, if you want to add weights or importances to different losses, you can use `loss.backward(torch.FloatTensor([-0.1, 1.0, 0.0001]))`.

This means to calculate `-0.1*d(loss1)/dw, d(loss2)/dw, 0.0001*d(loss3)/dw` simultaneously.

Comment: "if you want to add weights or importances to different losses, you can use loss.backward(torch.FloatTensor([-0.1, 1.0, 0.0001]))." -> This is true but somewhat misleading because the main reason why we pass `grad_tensors` is not to weigh them differently but they are gradients w.r.t. each element of corresponding tensors.

Answer (score 30):

Here, the output of forward(), i.e. y is a a 3-vector.

The three values are the gradients at the output of the network. They are usually set to 1.0 if y is the final output,  but can have other values as well, especially if y is part of a bigger network.

For eg. if x is the input, y = [y1, y2, y3] is an intermediate output which is used to compute the final output z,

Then,

```
dz/dx = dz/dy1 * dy1/dx + dz/dy2 * dy2/dx + dz/dy3 * dy3/dx
```

So here, the three values to backward are

```
[dz/dy1, dz/dy2, dz/dy3]
```

and then backward() computes dz/dx

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how is this useful in practice? I mean where do we need [dz/dy1, dz/dy2, dz/dy3] other than hardcoding backprop?

Comment: Is it correct to say that the provided gradient argument is the gradient computed in the latter part of the network?