# Pytorch, can't run backward() on even the most simple network without getting an error

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, feed-forward

I am new to pytorch and I can't run backward() on even the most simple network without generating an error. 
For example:

```
(Linear(6, 6)(Variable(torch.zeros([10, 6]))) - Variable(torch.zeros([10, 6]))).backward()
```

Throws the following error

```
{RuntimeError}element 0 of variables does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

What have I done wrong in the code to create this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a grad_output of matching shape as a parameter to backward:

(Linear(6, 6)(Variable(torch.zeros([10, 6]))) - Variable(torch.zeros([10, 6]))).backward(torch.zeros([10, 6]))

The following answer has more details: [Why should be the function backward be called only on 1 element tensor or with gradients w.r.t to Variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44264443/why-should-be-the-function-backward-be-called-only-on-1-element-tensor-or-with-g)

Answer (score 5):

This error happens when **PyTorch** could not find parameters of the model that have `requires_grad = True` i.e. all the model parameters have `requires_grad = False`.

There are different reasons, but it can be that you are freezing all the model, or that you're not correctly swapping the final layers of the model - for example, in rest net it should be `model.fc` and not `model.classifier`-.

You always have to be careful where you place this:

```
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```