# Understanding pytorch autograd

Tags: pytorch, autograd

I am trying to understand how pytorch autograd works. If I have functions y = 2x and z = y**2, if I do normal differentiation, I get dz/dx at x = 1 as 8 (dz/dx = dz/dy * dy/dx = 2y*2 = 2(2x)*2 = 8x). Or, z = (2x)**2 = 4x^2 and dz/dx = 8x, so at x = 1, it is 8.

If I do the same with pytorch autograd, I get 4

```
x = torch.ones(1,requires_grad=True)
y = 2*x
z = y**2
x.backward(z)
print(x.grad)
```

which prints

```
tensor([4.])
```

where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using [`Tensor.backward`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.Tensor.backward) wrong. To get the result you asked for you should use

```
x = torch.ones(1,requires_grad=True)
y = 2*x
z = y**2
z.backward()  # <-- fixed
print(x.grad)
```

The call to `z.backward()` invokes the back-propagation algorithm, starting at `z` and working back to each leaf node in the computation graph. In this case `x` is the only leaf node. After calling `z.backward()` the computation graph is reset and the `.grad` member of each leaf node is updated with the gradient of `z` with respect to the leaf node (in this case dz/dx).

What's actually happening in your original code? Well, what you've done is apply back-propagation starting at `x`. With no arguments `x.backward()` would simply result in `x.grad` being set to `1` since dx/dx = 1. The additional argument (`gradient`) is effectively a scale to apply to the resulting gradient. In this case `z=4` so you get `x.grad = z * dx/dx = 4 * 1 = 4`. If interested, you can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43451125/pytorch-what-are-the-gradient-arguments) for more information on what the `gradient` argument does.

Comment: Thanks! I was really confused by the pytorch tutorial https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html, but your explanation along with the link you provided helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you still have some confusion on autograd in pytorch, Please refer this:
This will be basic xor gate representation

```
import numpy as np
import torch.nn.functional as F
inputs = torch.tensor(
                [
                    [0, 0],
                    [0, 1],
                    [1, 0],
                    [1, 1]
                ]
            )
outputs = torch.tensor(
                [
                    0,
                    1,
                    1,
                    0
                ],
        )
weights = torch.randn(1, 2)
weights.requires_grad = True #set it as true for gradient computation

bias = torch.randn(1, requires_grad=True) #set it as true for gradient computation

preds = F.linear(inputs, weights, bias) #create a basic linear model
loss = (outputs - preds).mean()
loss.backward()
print(weights.grad) # this will print your weights
```