# pytorch Gradient with respect to 3D input

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow2.0

I want to construct sobolev network for 3D input regression

In TensorFlow, the gradients of neural network model can be computed using `tf.gradient` like:

```py
dfdx,dfdy,dfdz = tf.gradients(pred,[x,y,z])
```

Let M be a torch neural network with 5 layers.
If X is a set of (x,y,z)  (3dim data)
and M.forward(X)  is a 1 dim output

How can I compute like gradient of M.forward(X) with respect to X?  Something like:

```py
tf.gradient(M.forward(X),X)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compute gradient of this function for  example

> y_i = 5*(x_i + 1)²
> Create tensor of size 2x1 filled with 1's that requires gradient

```
x = torch.ones(2, requires_grad=True)
```

Simple linear equation with x tensor created

```
y = 5 * (x + 1) ** 2
```

Let take o as multiple dimension equation

o = 1/2 *sum(y_i)
in python

```
o = (1/2) * torch.sum(y)
```

you can compute grad with

```
o.backward()
x.grad
```

you can get more information here https://www.deeplearningwizard.com/deep_learning/practical_pytorch/pytorch_gradients/

Comment: I want to get gradients of neural network model,  'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63026358/pytorch-gradients-of-neural-network-for-3-dim-input-1-dim-output-regression'

Comment: you can get more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43451125/pytorch-what-are-the-gradient-arguments